# Django Query is being called every time the variable attributed to it is called

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I have this code:

```
players = room.player_set.all().order_by('?')  # mix the players
```

The 'order_by' is to get a random order of elements, which is needed for this case, and not expensive to the database since there is at most 3 elements in the player_set.

Every time the variable 'players' is called the query is made... meaning, every time the variable is called (for example, in print) the value of 'players' changes as well...

I've tried deepcopy with no success.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Apparently since the content of the query can change, the query is recalled as I suspected: explanation here [Django : random ordering(order_by('?')) makes additional query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961092/django-random-orderingorder-by-makes-additional-query)

This new code works...

```
players = list(room.player_set.all())
    
random.shuffle(players)  # mix the players
```

It is strange that the query is called every time though... I want what's in the DB at that time, not what's there when I use the variable...

Comment: What do you mean everytime its called?

Comment: @Sayse
if I do:
print(players)
print(players)
print(players)
print(players)
it outputs different order of elements every time (meaning that the value is not being stored in memory, it is doing the query to the DB every time I print the variable)